# How do I show only one specific post with comments and author box on the homepage in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show the full post with comments and author box on the home page just as if the actual link to the post was clicked. I will set the canonical on the actual post to point to the home page for seo purposes.

I've seen some code out there, but so far nothing that matches my exact needs.

I only want to display 1 WordPress post on the homepage with the comments and author box below the post. And I want to be able to specify which post will be the one that gets displayed on the homepage. (which post id#)

To add to this, I also need the rel="author" to be visible in the header section. I'm using WordPress SEO by yoast and have selected to not show rel="author" for pages. And all code out there I've tried that shows a single post on the home page treats it as if it is a page instead of a post, therefore removing the rel="author" from the head area.

Please do not reply with how to set the number of posts in the Reading tab or how to set a static page. I already know that. That won't work for my needs.

In summary, when I go to my home page I will see the article I wrote along with the comments and author box below it and rel="author" in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to set your homepage as a static page, and build a custom template for that page. In the editor, create a custom field that allows your to select a blog post to feature (look into Advanced Custom Fields plugin for easy custom fields), grab that custom field value, and use that to build either a WP_Query, or just call the various bits of information using the ID of that post. The trickiest part is getting the_content() by ID. Here's how you can do that:

1. Add this function to the functions.php file:

   function get_the_content_by_id($post_id) {
       $page_data = get_page($post_id);
       if ($page_data) {
           return $page_data->post_content;
       }else{ 
           return false;
       }
   }
2. Call your function in your page template like this:

   echo get_the_content_by_id([INSERT YOUR DESIRED POST ID HERE]);

If you make a php file in your Theme directory called front-page.php, that will automatically appear as the template for your static home page.

Now as far as the rel="author" thing, I don't know anything about that, so I unfortunately cannot help with that.

Also, I'm unsure why my code is losing it's formatting here.